# How to assign values to a jquery object using for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have tried several ways to create a parallax effect on my images where each image has it's own random speed. I think the best way for me to achieve it is by assigning a speed value to each image. However I am not sure how to do this.

```
var img_list = [];
$.each($('.gallery_image'), function(e) {
    img_list.append($(this));
});

for(x in img_list) {
    ran = Math.round(Math.random() * (11 - 1) + 1);
    speed = ran.toString() + "px";
    x.speed = speed;
}
```

This is what I came up with. I know that `x.speed` is not an actual thing, but I am using that to illustrate what I am trying to accomplish.

This is a website that has exactly what I am looking for on the main page, but I want the movement to be on scroll. [EXAMPLE](http://cs.kenji-special.info/)

Comment: That `for..in` won't work.

Comment: I know, but I'm not sure how to assign a speed value to the jquery objects

Comment: Why don't you use $.each to loop the img_list ?

Comment: x is a key (1,2,3...) so you need img_list[x].speed

Comment: Could you print.the content of img_list? Didnyou try to iterate with for (i=0; i<img_list.length; i++)??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for(var x in img_list) {
    var ran = Math.round(Math.random() * (11 - 1) + 1);
    img_list[x].speed = ran.toString() + "px";
}
```

Comment: Sorry been coding for about 8 hours straight and its 2am. Thank you that works. Do you have a suggestion on how to make the parallax? Just with a .css changing the position on scroll?

Answer (score 1):

Use push

```
var img_list = [];
$.each($('.gallery_image'), function(e) {
    img_list.push($(this));
});
```

but in this case you don't need a loop because `$('.gallery_image')` is a collection of objects

In the second loop you can use a each loop and save the speed as a data attribute:

```
$('.gallery_image').each(function(i,x){
    ran = Math.round(Math.random() * (11 - 1) + 1);
    speed = ran.toString() + "px";
    $(x).data('speed',speed);
});
```

Comment: *"$('.gallery_image') is a array of objects"* - Well, it's a jQuery object, which is array-like (but not an actual array). Might be better to use `.data()` rather than `.attr()`.

Comment: @nnnnnn thnx for the feedback

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if this is relative or not ,but I made a demo .
Hope this helps.

To move image set left `css` property of `dom`.

### DEMO

https://jsfiddle.net/vikrant47/yem6f0Ls/4/